# How to pass a Cursor Via IPC in android

Tags: android

I have a Cursor which is generated in a separate process as part of a content provider query(). I want to return this cursor back to the UI. Since I am using AIDL for the communication between the content provider and the separate process, it is not possible to define the cursor in the AIDL file because it does not implement the Parcelable interface. How can I solve the issue?

Jainish CS

Comment: Can you not use ContentResolver to access the provider from the other process?

Comment: As @IanWarwick said, this is exactly what the ContentProvider/ContentResolver pattern is designed for. Have your process access the ContentProvider directly through a ContentResolver, and you'll have a process-local Cursor.

Comment: Hi Thank You for the comment.Actually the contentProvider starts a service.When the UI does a query() It goes to the contentProvider which issues a getData() on the AIDL Interface and which has to return the cursor.The service is an Isolated process so marshaling is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any direct way to solve this Issue.But what I did was via DataUtils we can get the rows from the cursor add to a list.this List I have passed to the ContentProvider.The contentProvider creates a MatrixCursor and converts to Cursor and send back to the UI. There could have been a better solution If able to read the raws[] from the CursorWindow.